# Shiny: subset a reactive dataframe based on a reactive column name

Tags: r, shiny, subset, reactive

I have a reactive dataframe `df()`, and reactive column names from this dataframe, `slectedName()`. I would like to subset this `df()` based on the reactive column name.

I have tried with the following approaches, but none of them worked. How should I do it?

Thanks a lot.

```
1. df()$selectedName()

2. df() %>% dplyr::select(selectedName())
```

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example.  TRy `select(all_of(selectedName()))`

Comment: @akrun, Thanks a lot. I found out that df()[, selectedName()] works.